Generalization of compactness and local compactness
Consider the operation $r_X(A) = \overline{A}\setminus A$ in a space $X$. Here, suppose that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space.
Call a space $A$ to be $n$-compact in $X$, if $r_X^n(A) = \emptyset$ where $r_X^n$ means the operation $r_X$ iterated $n$ times.
Being $1$-compact is equivalent to being compact Hausdorff, and being $2$-compact is equivalent to being locally compact Hausdorff.
Suppose that $r_X^n(A) = \emptyset$ and let $Y$ be another compact Hausdorff space that $A$ is embedded in. Does $r_Y^n(A) = \emptyset$?
That is, is the property of being $n$-compact independent of the embedding of $A$ into $X$?

The property seems to actually have its uses for creating examples of spaces with only zero-dimensional compactifications. See this and this question of mine for example.

Of course, this is really a generalization of,"closed," aince it generalizes closed subspaces. It just happens that closed subspaces of compact spaces are are exactly the compact subspaces.

Yes, the property $r_X^n(A) = \emptyset$ is a generalization of being closed. I am asking if this is invariant of the compact Hausdorff space that $A$ is embedded in, just like for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$. Thus, we could be talking about $n$-compact space, instead of an $n$-compact subset of $X$.

What if $A$ is locally compact but cannot be embedded into a compact Hausdorff space? Would you call such an $A$ $2$-compact?

@RobArthan To be more precise, I am trying to generalize compact Hausdorff and locally compact Hausdorff spaces, so that in this setting every locally compact Hausdorff space embedds into its one-point compactification. I've edited the question to make it clearer

Thanks - that clarifies things.

Just to give an additional remark, any space $A$ embedds as a subset of a compact space $X$ with $r_X^2(A) = \emptyset$, since we can take $X = A\cup {\infty}$ to be Alexandroff extension of $A$ (assuming $A$ isn't compact, if it is take $A = X$). So the property of $r_X^2(A) = \emptyset$ in some compact (but not Hausdorff) space $X$ doesn't give us local compactness. However, perhaps the property that $r_X^2(A) = \emptyset$ for all compact spaces $X$ that $A$ is embedded in, does give us some local compactness-like property even when $X$ is not Hausdorff. I leave that for others to research
